# How do I focus on an object's center (Numpad period not working)

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I'm running through the donut tutorial, and when I click on the torus and press Numpad period, it focuses me on the side of the object.
[image: Donut not focusing on center]

I have the center set to: "Geometry to Origin" and it's not rotating about the origin either. I found a way to fix this the other day, but I'm new to blender and haven't touched it in a week and forgot the fix. Can't seem to find it again.

Comment: Switch to *Edit Mode* and check if there is any *loose geometry*. Most likely one extra vertex you can't see in Object Mode*...

Comment: ...  and if there is, say, a stray vertex, then going to the Object tab > Viewport Display panel, and checking 'Bounds' might help you find it.

Answer (score 6):

To fix the <kbd>.</kbd> shortcut, press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring a sidebar, go to *View* > *View Lock* and disable *Lock to 3D Cursor*

[image]

As for the rotating pivot point problem, you can change that at the middle top of the 3D Viewport.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, this was caused by "Lock to Object" which I enabled somehow.

[image: before]

[image: after]

This menu can be found by pressing "N" to reveal the sidebar.